# Bizarre RMI errors when trying to expose an MBeanServer over JMX programmatically

Tags: java, rmi, jmx, mbeans, mbeanexporter

In [the documentation on Java management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html), in the section headed ***"Mimicking Out-of-the-Box Management Using the JMX Remote API"*** (see bottom of page), it shows you how you can manually expose your MBeanServer via JMX. Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    final Map<String, Object> env = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    final SslRMIClientSocketFactory csf = new SslRMIClientSocketFactory();
    env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, csf);
    final SslRMIServerSocketFactory ssf = new SslRMIServerSocketFactory();
    env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, ssf);

    final int port = 32154;
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.randomIDs", "true");
    final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port /*, csf, ssf */);
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:" + port + "/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mbs);
    cs.start();
```

If you try and run this code, this exception is repeatedly thrown (and you cannot remotely connect to the server):

```
26-Nov-2015 16:42:21:085: [sun.rmi.transport.tcp - FINE] [14]: RMI TCP Connection(4)-10.210.50.223: terminated with exception:

Exception in 14: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:818)
  at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
  at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:686)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I thought *"it must be that the registry is not created with the relevant socket factories"*, so I uncommented the relevant arguments to `LocateRegistry.createRegistry`. But now this exception is thrown (and the application fails to start)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://:32154/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint]
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:804)
  at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:417)
  at gsa.core.monitor.ExposeMBeansViaSsl.main(ExposeMBeansViaSsl.java:32)
```

**Note**: the application is run with the relevant `javax.net.ssl` system properties set, as described in the tutorial. Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Don't know whether it's part of the problem or totally unrelated, but note that you can specify more ports in the jmx rmi url, which you might need to do if you're creating your own registry. See: http://www.joekearney.co.uk/posts/jmx-in-a-dmz/

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference - thanks for the link though!

Comment: @oxbow_lakes were you able to solve this?

Comment: No; the context of this issue was the securing of internal JMX endpoints. We ended up taking a different approach